# KENDO UI - Trying to add div at run time

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying to add a div with id at run time. then at same time trying to add kendo ui chart into that div. But i am unable to do that. If anyone has any suggestion.its urgent. I have one textbox in which i am entering a value, then trying to add that number.

Here is my code for it:

```
function createChart() { 
    var noofcharts = document.getElementById('noOfCharts').value; 

    for(var i=1;i<=noofcharts;i++){ 
        var varSlid = "chart"+i; 
        var div= $("<div id='+varSlid+' style='display:inline-block;width: 20%; height: 20%;border:2px solid;'></div>" ); 
        $(document.body).append(div); 
        div.kendoChart({ series: [ { data: [1, 2] } ] }); 
    } 
}
```

Here is the error:

> Error: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared.
>   The document will render with garbled text in some browser
>   configurations if the document contains characters from outside the
>   US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in
>   the document or in the transfer protocol

Comment: here is my code for it

Comment: function createChart() {
 var noofcharts = document.getElementById('noOfCharts').value;
 for(var i=1;i<=noofcharts;i++){
     var varSlid = "chart"+i;
     var div= $("<div id='+varSlid+' style='display:inline-block;width: 20%; height: 20%;border:2px solid;'></div>" );
    $(document.body).append(div);
           div.kendoChart({
                 series: [ 
                       { data: [1, 2] }
                       ]
                    });
 }
     
                }

Comment: Error: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: Please take a look on other questions to see how to ask properly. Those informations that you're posting as a comment SHOULD be on the post body!!

Comment: What is not working in you code? Try it here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/QQcqP/

Comment: @OnaBai His idea is to gave every wrapper (div) of chart identical id. like chart1, chart2, chart3, ...

Comment: @kavita your welcome kavita. Please check mark my solution as accept if it is your answer and give +1 if you like. also remove your 3 first comments, to cleanup here.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function createChart() {
    var noofcharts = $('#noOfCharts').val();

    for (var i = 1; i <= noofcharts; i++) {
        var varSlid = "chart" + i;
        var div = $("<div id='"+varSlid+"' style='display:inline-block;width: 20%; height: 20%;border:2px solid;'></div>");
        $(document.body).append(div);
        div.kendoChart({ series: [
            { data: [1, 2] }
        ] });
    }
}
```

this should generate something like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="chart1" style="display: inline-block; width: 20%; height: 20%; border: 2px solid; position: relative;" data-role="chart" class="k-chart">
    <!-- some codes for kendo chart -->
    </div>
    <div id="chart2" style="display: inline-block; width: 20%; height: 20%; border: 2px solid; position: relative;" data-role="chart" class="k-chart">
    <!-- some codes for kendo chart -->
    </div>
    <div id="chart3" style="display: inline-block; width: 20%; height: 20%; border: 2px solid; position: relative;" data-role="chart" class="k-chart">
    <!-- some codes for kendo chart -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the difference between your code and the original one? Other than the way that you get `noofcharts` but they are equivalent?

Comment: @OnaBai The difference is here `...id='"+varSlid+"' style=...` , he forgots two `"` before and after `+`. and why you vote me down?